# When changing the value of a field with Javascript, Safari keeps the placeholder visible

Tags: jquery, css, safari, placeholder

Run the following in Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/gkatsanos/2355m5ds/

When I am changing .val() of an input field without focusing on it manually in Safari, the placeholder remains.
[image: safari bug]

```js
$('a').on('click', () => {
  $('#stuff').val('lala');
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="stuff" type="text" placeholder="This Won't get removed in Safari when we change the value of the input">
  <a href="#">Click this</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Unable to replicate on Safari 10.0.1 on OSX, your fiddle works fine

Comment: added screenshot. @RoryMcCrossan try to only click once, when you click twice it goes away. if it works the first time, refresh and try once more.

Comment: Yep - still works here. First click or tenth click.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I posted this under the Apple community forum a couple of weeks ago.   I have tried upgrading jquery to the newest version and no joy.   My guess is its an Apple change in webkit that is not compatible with jquery.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs only if you've opened the Javascript console in Safari.

For example, if you restart Safari or open a new window and run the jsfiddle, it will work fine. If you select Develop->Show Javascript Console, then it starts doing the weird behavior, and it continues doing so even after you close the console.

I've reported this bug to Apple (#33759204).

Comment: The JSFiddle provided by George Katsanos above reproduces the issue without showing the JavaScript Console. While I'm not the person who downvoted you, perhaps that's why you were.